# SQL UNION OR JOIN 2 SELECTION

Tags: sql, sql-server

I will made a simple exemple to understand better what I'm trying to do:

I have `Selection 1` witch takes data from 4 tables with severals `inner join`. The results is like image shown bellow:

[image]

I have `Selection 2` witch takes data from another 4 tables. 
The only difference between this 2 results of the selections is the column 4.

The results is like image shown bellow:

[image]

The results I want is like this:

[image]

If I make `UNION ALL` he put the values underneath (the result is with 20 rows), and I don't need like that.
If I Make Join between them I have 10x10=100 rows.

EXEMPLE LINK: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9d07b/1)

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: You want JOIN instead of UNION ALL

Comment: With Join of this 2 selection the result is Cartesian Product 10x10=100 rows

Comment: @Marius check the answer it will not cross join here table 1 and table 2 having only matching records

Comment: @Marius Please check my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get data from both selection with inner joins and display only required columns from both selections

```
;WITH CTE1
AS
(
    SELECT * FROM SELECTION1
)
,CTE2
AS
(
    SELECT * FROM SELECTION2
)

SELECT
CTE1.UNAME,
CTE1.PRE_NAME,
CTE1.TIME,
CTE1.FIRST_VALUE,
CTE2.FINAL_VALUE
FROM CTE1
INNER JOIN CTE2
ON CTE1.UNAME=CTE2.UNAME
AND CTE1.PRE_NAME=CTE2.PRE_NAME
AND CTE1.TIME=CTE2.TIME
```

**UPDATE**

[**FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a581d/1)

I have tried to get something unique from both tables so used `ROW_NUMBER()`. This might help. Joins with duplicate values in both tables will make it 10x10 rows only which you don't want.

```
WITH CTE1
AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY U_NAME) AS NO, * FROM SELECTION1
)
,CTE2
AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY U_NAME) AS NO,* FROM SELECTION2
)

SELECT
CTE1.U_NAME,
CTE1.PRE_NAME,
CTE1.TIME,
CTE1.FIRST_VALUE,
CTE2.FINAL_VALUE
FROM CTE1
INNER JOIN CTE2
ON CTE1.NO=CTE2.NO
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
WITH CTE1
AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UD_NAME) AS NO, * FROM 
(
SELECT R0507UNIT_.R0507NAME_ AS UD_NAME,
R0101MAPAR.R0101NAME_ AS PRE_NAME,
TO_CHAR(D0903GSCHH.D0903TFROM + INTERVAL '2' HOUR, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS TIME_FROM,
D0904GSCHI.D0904POWER AS FINAL_POWER
FROM D0904GSCHI
INNER JOIN D0903GSCHH
ON
D0904GSCHI.D0903TFROM = D0903GSCHH.D0903TFROM
AND D0904GSCHI.D0903ID___ = D0903GSCHH.D0903ID___
INNER JOIN R0101MAPAR
ON
D0903GSCHH.R0101ID___ = R0101MAPAR.R0101ID___
INNER JOIN R0507UNIT_
ON
D0903GSCHH.R0507ID___=R0507UNIT_.R0507ID___
WHERE D0903GSCHH.D0903TFROM >= TO_DATE('07.02.2017 20:00','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
AND D0903GSCHH.D0903TFROM < TO_DATE('08.02.2017 20:00','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
--AND R0507UNIT_.R0507NAME_ = 'BUCV3'
) AS A --THIS IS AN ALIAS
)
```

Comment: The result is with 20 rows

Comment: Basically you need something unique in both selections to join on. Otherwise one record of a section will bind to 10 records of another selection and thus you will not get required result.

Comment: Here: [Exemple](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ad75d/1) is working, but in my case it doesn't.

Comment: An error occurred `missing expression` at row where is:  `SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY U_NAME) AS NO, * FROM SELECTION1`

Comment: I don't get any errors, results are fine as you expected. Run it in MSSQL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135366/discussion-between-marius-and-hemal).

Comment: The error apear at this line: `SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UD_NAME) AS NO, * FROM `

Comment: You forgot to gave alias to inner select in both CTEs

Comment: Please select as answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT          A.U_NAME,
                A.PRE_NAME,
                A.TIME,
                A.FIRST_VALUE,
                B.FINAL_VALUE

FROM            Selection1 AS A

INNER JOIN      Selection2 AS B
    ON          A.U_NAME = B.U_NAME
        AND     A.PRE_NAME = B.PRE_NAME
        AND     A.TIME = B.TIME
```

Comment: This Query makes Cartesian Product, I have 20 rows

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the two queries together using an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT   s1.U_NAME
        ,s1.PRE_NAME
        ,s1.TIME
        ,s1.FIRST_VALUE
        ,s2.FINAL_VALUE
FROM (
    -- First query
    SELECT U_NAME, PRE_NAME, TIME, FIRST_VALUE
    FROM Selection1
) s1
INNER JOIN (
    -- Second query
    SELECT U_NAME, PRE_NAME, TIME, FINAL_VALUE
    FROM Selection1
) s2
    ON s1.U_NAME = s2.U_NAME
    AND s1.PRE_NAME = s2.PRE_NAME
    AND s1.TIME = s2.TIME
;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I consider the two inputs as tables, you can achieve the desired results with another join between the these tables (But i will not suggest it due to performance issues).

```
SELECT 
TBL1.U_NAME,TBL1.PRE_NAME,TBL1.TIME,TBL1.FIRST_VALUE,TBL2.FINAL_VALUE FROM  
FROM FIRSTTABLE TBL1 INNER JOIN SECONDTABLE TBL2 ON TBL1.U_NAME=TBL2.U_NAME 
AND TBL1.PRE_NAME=TBL2.PRE_NAME AND TBL1.TIME=TBL2.TIME
```

I see your already have some inner joins to get data in FirstTable and SecondTable. If both of these queries are using common tables to bring data, you can do it in a single query also. If I am understanding your problem correctly, Union is not required for the kind of resultset you are looking for.

If you can provide the complete query it would give more context and can provide a better solution.

Comment: Selection 2 takes data from another 4 tables

Comment: As per the question query 1 also takes data from 4 tables. Are all the four tables different for query1 and query2?

Comment: Yes, I have 8 tables with different data, 4 in the first selection and 4 in the second selection.

Comment: Thanks. So in that case the query given will work fine. Just replace the FirstTable with query1 and SecondTable with Query 2.

'SELECT 
TBL1.U_NAME,TBL1.PRE_NAME,TBL1.TIME,TBL1.FIRST_VALUE,TBL2.FINAL_VALUE FROM  
FROM (Query1) AS TBL1 INNER JOIN (Query2) AS TBL2 ON TBL1.U_NAME=TBL2.U_NAME 
AND TBL1.PRE_NAME=TBL2.PRE_NAME AND TBL1.TIME=TBL2.TIME '

Comment: In this case the query is like @Hemal, answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN TRAN
CREATE TABLE #temp (U_Name Nvarchar(20),PRE_Name Nvarchar(20),Time Datetime,firstValue int)
CREATE TABLE #temp1 (U_Name Nvarchar(20),PRE_Name Nvarchar(20),Time Datetime,firstValue int)
INSERT INTO #temp
Select 'GV','NMOP','10.02.2017', 90 UNION ALL
Select 'GV','NMOP','10.02.2017', 100 UNION ALL
Select 'GV','NMOP','10.02.2017', 120 UNION ALL
Select 'GV','NMOP','10.02.2017', 300 UNION ALL
Select 'GV','NMOP','10.02.2017', 200 UNION ALL
Select 'GV','NMOP','10.02.2017', 100 UNION ALL
Select 'GV','NMOP','10.02.2017', 50 UNION ALL
Select 'GV','NMOP','10.02.2017', 60 UNION ALL
Select 'GV','NMOP','10.02.2017', 70 UNION ALL
Select 'GV','NMOP','10.02.2017', 10 

INsert into #temp1
Select 'GV','NMOP','10.02.2017', 60 UNION ALL
Select 'GV','NMOP','10.02.2017', 52 UNION ALL
Select 'GV','NMOP','10.02.2017', 10 UNION ALL
Select 'GV','NMOP','10.02.2017', 300 UNION ALL
Select 'GV','NMOP','10.02.2017', 33 UNION ALL
Select 'GV','NMOP','10.02.2017', 100 UNION ALL
Select 'GV','NMOP','10.02.2017', 50 UNION ALL
Select 'GV','NMOP','10.02.2017', 56 UNION ALL
Select 'GV','NMOP','10.02.2017', 99 UNION ALL
Select 'GV','NMOP','10.02.2017', 10 

 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY U_NAME) AS Rowno,a.U_Name, a.PRE_Name,a.Time,a.firstValue into #t from #temp a
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY U_NAME) AS Rowno, b.U_Name, b.PRE_Name,b.Time,b.firstValue as finalValue INTO #TT from #temp1 b

 SELECT a.U_Name,a.PRE_Name,a.Time,a.firstValue,  b.finalValue 
 FROM #t  a
 INNER JOIN #TT b ON a.Rowno=b.Rowno AND a.U_Name=b.U_Name AND a.PRE_Name=b.PRE_Name AND a.time=b.Time


ROLLBACK TRAN
```